# Free multi location inventory solution

Tags: self-hosted, web, inventory

I'm a member of a small non-profit club/association that does firework displays. As we are growing we are starting to keep a larger inventory of material. I'd like to find a software solution to manage that instead of Excel sheets on the president's computer.

One important feature is that it must support multiple "warehouses" as we have two of them and need both an overall view of our stock as well as inventory lists for inspection purposes.

We also need to track net explosive mass stored in each warehouse. So additional fields and some way to aggregate/export/report on them is essential.

Anything that's going to incur annual costs is going to be tricky since we already only barely manage financially... I do have a host that can run anything PHP.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use this sort of thing, so cannot make a recommendation. However, the are 259 possibles to wade through at https://sourceforge.net/directory/language:php/?q=inventory  Or you could code your own?

Comment: @Mawg I have started to code my own. But progress is intermittent...

Comment: I feel your pain. Take a look at SourceForge, but bear in mind that it is sometimes easier to do it from scratch than to modify someone else's code if it doesn't match your needs exactly.  As you describe it, Excel ought to be able to handle it, although I would probably go for Python or PHP with MySql or Sqlite

Comment: @Similar needs, and also started coding on my own solution in (PHP/MySQL). Same country (at the very west). Maybe can we join our forces.